# How to map json into interface object in Angular

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular. (Version 11).

I'm not quite sure what I am missing.  I am calling an API from my service to get a JSON object and return it into the interface object that I created.

However when I look at the value country in the html it is not my country interface it is the full object that came from the api. (My interface should only have a subset of values).

Service:

```
  getCountry(): void {
    const name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
    this.countryService.getCountry(name)
      .subscribe(x => this.country = x);
  };
```

Component:

```
export class CountryDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  country: Country;
  
  constructor(
    private countryService: CountryService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCountry();
    const x = this.country;
  }

  getCountry(): void {
    const name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
    this.countryService.getCountry(name)
      .subscribe(x => this.country = x);
  };
```

Country:

```
export interface Country {
  name: string,
  alpha2Code: string,
  alpha3Code: string,
  capital: string,
  region: string,
  subregion: string,
  population: number,
  demonym: string,
  area: number,
  gini: number
  flag: string
}
```

component.html

```
{{country | json}}
```

API: https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/aruba?fullText=true

Result from html:

```
[ { "name": "Aruba", "topLevelDomain": [ ".aw" ], "alpha2Code": "AW", "alpha3Code": "ABW", "callingCodes": [ "297" ], "capital": "Oranjestad", "altSpellings": [ "AW" ], "region": "Americas", "subregion": "Caribbean", "population": 107394, "latlng": [ 12.5, -69.96666666 ], "demonym": "Aruban", "area": 180, "gini": null, "timezones": [ "UTC-04:00" ], "borders": [], "nativeName": "Aruba", "numericCode": "533", "currencies": [ { "code": "AWG", "name": "Aruban florin", "symbol": "ƒ" } ], "languages": [ { "iso639_1": "nl", "iso639_2": "nld", "name": "Dutch", "nativeName": "Nederlands" }, { "iso639_1": "pa", "iso639_2": "pan", "name": "(Eastern) Punjabi", "nativeName": "ਪੰਜਾਬੀ" } ], "translations": { "de": "Aruba", "es": "Aruba", "fr": "Aruba", "ja": "アルバ", "it": "Aruba", "br": "Aruba", "pt": "Aruba", "nl": "Aruba", "hr": "Aruba", "fa": "آروبا" }, "flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/abw.svg", "regionalBlocs": [], "cioc": "ARU" } ]
```

Comment: This isn't a [mre], but note that generic types **do not** do any kind of casting or conversion at runtime. Types are erased, JavaScript doesn't have them. I've collated a few related questions [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing few fundamental concepts :

1. The API returns an Array of countries( with only one value) so the variable to hold this value should be :

   `this.countryService.getCountry(name).subscribe(x => this.country = x[0]);`
2. Interfaces are used for static type checking , at run time there is no interface because the code gets transpiled into Javascript and interface doesn't exist in JS. `Interface` is not meant to be used like the way you're using.

here's a good read :   https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

3. You need to create a class and assign the values manually if you want to keep subset of values.

```
 name: string;
 alpha2Code: string;
 alpha3Code: string;
 capital: string;
 region: string;
 subregion: string;
 population: number;
 demonym: string;
 area: number;
 gini: number;
 flag: string;

 constructor(d: any) {
   this.name = d.name;
   ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to strip out your additional properties, you need a `class`. An `interface` doesn't actually do anything. It's strictly a data contract or schema for a model. If you set something and there are additional properties, they will be set on the interface.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=35&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBtGBvGAiMBAWwFM8AufAQQCcBXAIwTwBp8oQAHAGRIDcSAGwAiIIggCWYCpnwA6BAHc8MALps8CQZwAWCAEwBhEHDKU8VAOqt8W3QgDMx0zIsAhaxuBbBUgObOJBAyWHj6AJwA7Crq%20N6cEsiCrgDyNAhgAFZByHA2moJQAMqcQr5gfsGUoVYxGjQkfhLgrlSkNBLewRoQjA1NLeaGCB0MDCQZ%20ZxcdIJIzdKUAIwADJEO4QAsGnNQghUhMEv6cgCsbAC0AGzhcuFXD49XahqmROAAnkSt9EzSGiMJjIlgAOFYaJpgCQyMCzQQaKASUgAL3AQUOeAAqgAVQwXFabcgrFZ1fAMEA0Uw0KqYWIEeYCAByxDM1F%20zA0sPanUCrlODgc%20WAdBoDTAwAk6OqODiJlZFksAHF8oRSD9GBkYAAzQQUqT5CBfcnJcyAJMAVABfF74OYVOgIPxS2S4PASCAgK4bAD6S1cYGSGjdHu9%20j9gjynJZrmEdCgwB0KoZJGZavMjJIVNtcGCMAtbBdQc94R9rk4HPwhZDpcmkdT%20AAFABRBDQEg0MAAShgAAU6FkEAxoZHEUyo%20ZAFRQgAcoQA4UIA%20KEANFCAAShLda8FB0pBdgsaS6XOZaBr8k6LOz8lqaOqmPlMsxzIAihkA1wyABYZ8olL%20W8AwL-vTxpOFB3xVE02UPDQdG-ECrw0LVb3wQAiMEARjBAAkwQAKMEAcjBLWguY-FcHQoCgTgIHIAB6YiGmgUA%203XSUIDkEg6GIxBkGIgdFDkCA%20Bw%20pGgWLQ3F1YAaQwOkJRAYBWgAJUxFdVAAbgAKHk4A5ggCAYGMKiaA%20HB5JgGBVRIShoA6CoFL0uw9CMOUjOo0zdJgCzHECGyTL8MyYHiRItBc-x3P6BYfLsvTei-HjwECtz7OmThZnmcL9LoIhxhody3k%20IgIvcwEEEoLlkvcyEJFyxL8vsnUHUyxS9NASB1zoYAOBoes4EoDIPi7bB7L0qAdDdOQDLQeB%20pZdzut62jHKs0xBrgBRtEswJ3IteTlqU8B3UEEg5F1Px6zAEhFHUkBNI%20ZqkAQDAVlUDsO1koA)

```
class Country {
  name: string;
  alpha2Code: string;
  alpha3Code: string;
  capital: string;
  region: string;
  subregion: string;
  population: number;
  demonym: string;
  area: number;
  gini: number;
  flag: string;

  constructor(d: any) {
    this.name = d.name;
    this.alpha2Code = d.alpha2Code;
    ...
  }
}
```